# change html in blogger soho theme

Tags: html, css

After asking a few question the Help Center for Blogger I was directed here.
I am using the Soho Theme and have attempted with the help of Blogger Experts to change so CSS or HTML coding. As of now nothing is working.

I want to use a font that is not offered in the header above the image. I found and downloaded a font and use the CSS code they provided, entered it and applied to them but it won't show.

The other thing I would like to do is change the size that is used for that theme. I was given the code to enter into CSS, applied and it shows in the preview but when I actually view the website, it's still the standard large size. I even tried several different size images but it still goes to the size that seems to be part of the theme. Is there a way to use a smaller image?

Any help with these two issues is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you include some code snippets that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes. I will do that after work. Thanks.

Comment: I actually got the first part of my question fixed by the suggestion of a friend. So I have a font I am happy with in the header. It appears it has decreased the size of the "fixed" image on the soho theme but I might be incorrect. I did a screenshot but don't see a way to post or upload it. This is my first time posting on the forum. Can you tell me how to do that and I'll post that.

Comment: Anybody have a answer for this. The only replies I have received are three spam emails.